# List returns null while working with two list views

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have two ListViews within one Layout.

I manipulate data within a single List whenever the user clicks on any item from both these Listviews. Both ListViews are basically used to filter the data within a single ArrayList.

The problem is when the user clicks on the list item of the second listView and then on the list item of the first ListView, the ArrayList becomes null.

```
  mCatagory1List.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
mCatagory2List.setOnItemClickListener(this);


private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener 
            {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) 
        {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item


            displayView(position);
        }
    }

 private void displayView(int position) 
    {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        companyList.clear();
        if(position>0)
        {
            String myPosition = null;

            myPosition =  navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle();
            companyList = Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(myFinalList, new ArticleFilter(myPosition)));

            fragment = new HomeFragment(params,getApplicationContext(),companyList);
        }
        else if(position==0 && (navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle()=="All Items"))
        {

            fragment = new HomeFragment(params,getApplicationContext(),myFinalList);
        }




        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mainLinearLayout);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
    {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position)
        {
        case 0:
            companyList = myFinalList;
            fragment =fragment = new HomeFragment(params,getApplicationContext(),companyList);

            break;

        case 1:

            companyList = myFinalList;
        Collections.sort(companyList, new MyComparator());
        fragment = fragment = new HomeFragment(params,getApplicationContext(),companyList);

            break;

        case 2:
            companyList = myFinalList;
            Collections.sort(companyList, new CommentsComparator());
            fragment = fragment = new HomeFragment(params,getApplicationContext(),companyList);


            break;

        case 3:
            companyList = myFinalList;
            Collections.sort(companyList, new ViewsComparator());
            fragment = new HomeFragment(params,getApplicationContext(),companyList);

            break;




        }


        if (fragment != null)
{
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mCatagory2List.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mCatagory2List.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(catagoryList[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mainLinearLayout);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

its appear unclear for me, but at a rapid view, try to change it:

```
//...
  mCatagory1List.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
mCatagory2List.setOnItemClickListener(this);
//...
```

for this:

```
//...
mCatagory1List.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
mCatagory2List.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
//...
```

hope with help

Peace!